# I can't restore database from .bak file in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

When I select the .bak file it is nothing shown in the 'backup sets to restore' area below. This is the newest backup version from hosting server 2012.

If I  try restore a few months older .bak file from the same hosting server it works fine.

I am using ms sql 2012 Express.

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.2.9200.16384
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.10.9200.16660
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.18051
Operating System 6.2.9200

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue and the issue for me was that files were created by another user and permissions were not properly allocated.

Try updating the Login for the SQL Server Service to an Administrator on the box.